# Organizing the Controller Directory in Rails (3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing an application that is primarily an API gateway. In the expectation that we'll be developing multiple versions of the API over time and with the interest of having backward compatibility, I am looking to have something along the lines of:

http://host.domain.com/apiv1/:token/:module(/:id(:method))

Given this, what I am looking to do is to have a sub-routing system of my own within each API. What I'd like to have in terms of a file structure in the Controller directory is something akin to the following:

```
/app/controllers/apiv1_controller.rb
/app/controllers/apiv1/module_controller.rb
/app/controllers/apiv1/response_controller.rb
```

and eventually also have:

```
/app/controllers/apiv2_controller.rb
/app/controllers/apiv2/module_controller.rb
/app/controllers/apiv2/response_controller.rb
```

What this breaks down to is that I am unsure how to call methods within the controllers in the subdirectories, using something like:

```
return Apiv1::ResponseController.index
```

gives me:

```
undefined method `index' for Apiv1::ResponseController:Class
```

Any leads? Does this setup require that I explicitly "require" the requisite file manually?

Pasted Here in response to the question:

**routes.rb**

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :users
    match 'api-v1/:token/:module(/:id(/:method))' => 'apiv1#route'
    root :to => "welcome#index"
end
```

**apiv1_controller.rb**

```
class Apiv1Controller < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery
    respond_to :json

    def route
        Rails.logger.level = 0
        logger.info("ROUTE ACTION")
        logger.info("params: #{params}")
        Apiv1::ResponseController.index(params)
    end
end
```

**apiv1/response_controller.rb**

```
class Apiv1::ResponseController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery
    respond_to :json

    def index(params)
        Rails.logger.level = 0
        logger.info("INDEX ACTION")

        result = {
            'success' => true,
            'controller' => 'response',
            'api' => 'v1'
        }
        render :json => result
    end
end
```

Comment: does the controller actually have the index method defined in it? I know it might seem like a lame question ("Are you sure the computer is plugged in?") but if you don't generate the controller as part of scaffold or specify the actions if you generate it as a controller, you don't get that method.

Comment: Yup, it's a simple method for now, but I have it defined. (It just does some simple logging and a return)

Comment: AS another sidenote, I've tried different methods of calling the method and capitalizations, just on the off-chance it was something like that, no luck yet.

Comment: can you copy-paste these controllers excerpts please /app/controllers/apiv1_controller.rb
/app/controllers/apiv1/module_controller.rb

Comment: first 5-10 lines of each. And routes.rb also

Comment: Pastes added to original question.

Comment: You might want to consider to use [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) - it has built-in support for common conventions such as multiple formats, subdomain/prefix restriction, and versioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for versioning your REST APIs, you can use the [restful_route_version](https://github.com/gnufied/restful_route_version) gem. It also takes care of inheriting one version from another so that you don't rewrite the same REST APIs for every version.

Comment: Unfortunately we won't be sticking to the resource routing out of the box from rails, so I need something with a bit more flexibility.